# Using variable Lat Long with embedded Google map

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to set up a website that shows a map of various addresses, depending on which page you view. All of the information for each page is stored in a MySQL database, so I can't put in individual lat/long coordinates for each page because they are built realtime pulling from my database.

How can I incorporate the PHP variables that would pull the coordinates from my table into the jQuery for the Google map? I have no experience with jQuery, so it's possible this is a quick fix... I apologize if I am asking a silly question!

In a coding example, I'm wanting to do:

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$long),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Where $lat and $long are equal to $row['Latitude'] and $row['Longitude']

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try simply adding the php echo of your var

```
<script>
function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat .',' . $long ; ?>),
      zoom:5,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```